# HTML Agility Pack - removing nested strong and em tags

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I need to strip nested bold and italic tags from HTML but keep the content and also keep the top level bold or italic tag.

So for example the following:

```
<p><strong>Some text has<strong>been</strong>made bold</strong> and some text not bold</p>
```

Would become this:

```
<p><strong>Some text has been made bold</strong> and some text not bold</p>
```

Also this needs to work for multiple nested tags therefore the following:

```
<p><strong>Some text<strong> has<strong>been</strong>made bold</strong></strong> and some text not bold</p>
```

Would also become:

```
<p><strong>Some text has been made bold</strong> and some text not bold</p>
```

I started writing the following using HTML Agility pack and although this seems to work when there is only 1 nested bold tag it doesn't work correctly when there are multiple nested tags:

```
// Loop through bold and italic tags
List<string> boldAndItalicTagNames = new List<string>() { "strong", "em" };
var boldAndItalicTags = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(string.Join("|", 
boldAndItalicTagNames.Select(x => "//" + x)));
if (boldAndItalicTags != null)
{
    foreach (var tag in boldAndItalicTags)
    {
        // If tag doensn't have any child nodes (i.e. it is empty)
        if (!tag.HasChildNodes)
        {
            // Remove child and continue to next iteration
            tag.ParentNode.RemoveChild(tag);
            continue;
        }

        // If tag has children of same type (i.e. if strong tag has children strong tags)
        var childrenOfSameType = tag.ChildNodes.Where(x => x.Name == tag.Name).ToList();
        if (childrenOfSameType.Any())
        {
            // Loop through child nodes
            for (var i = childrenOfSameType.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                // Get child node and remove tags but keep content
                var child = childrenOfSameType[i];
                child.ParentNode.RemoveChild(child, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this is more complicated than I thought judging by the lack of replies. This doesn't have to be done using HTML Agility Pack if someone knows any other way of removing the nested tags?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following solution to this problem, it is probably not the best solution but it seems to be working therefore it will have to do for now unless anyone can think of anything better.

```
// Iterate through p tags
var pTags = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p");
if (pTags != null)
{
    foreach (var pTag in pTags)
    {
        // Iterate through bold and italic tags within P tags
        List<string> boldAndItalicTagNames = new List<string>() { "strong", "em" };
        var boldAndItalicTags = pTag.SelectNodes(string.Join("|", boldAndItalicTagNames.Select(x => ".//" + x)));
        if (boldAndItalicTags != null)
        {
            foreach (var tag in boldAndItalicTags)
            {
                // Remove any other nested tags
                tag.InnerHtml = tag.InnerHtml.Replace($"<{tag.Name}>", "").Replace($"</{tag.Name}>", "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```